# HTML Renders in IE7 but not in Firefox or Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

The following html in an `<iframe>` renders in IE7 but not in Firefox or Chrome?

```
var content = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.2//EN\"\"http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/DTD/xhtml-mobile12.dtd\">
<html>
 <body style=\"background-color:#0C0C0C; color:#FFFFFF\"> 
 Please Enter the credentials
 <form name=\"dynamicform\">
 <ul class=\"edgetoedge\" style=\"background-color:#0C0C0C;\"><li><div id=\"errorDiv\" style=\"color:red\"> </div></li> <li> <input id=\"Phone Number:_minLength\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"16\" /> </li>
 <li> </ul> </form> </body> </html>"
<script>
.....
var dynamicFormIframe = document.getElementById('dynamicFormIframe');
dynamicFormIframe = (dynamicFormIframe.contentWindow) ? dynamicFormIframe.contentWindow : (dynamicFormIframe.contentDocument.document) ? dynamicFormIframe.contentDocument.document : dynamicFormIframe.contentDocument;
        dynamicFormIframe.document.open();
        dynamicFormIframe.document.write(content);
....</sript>
<body><iframe id="dynamicFormIframe" src=""></frame></body >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dynamicFormIframe = (dynamicFormIframe.contentWindow) ? dynamicFormIframe.contentWindow : (dynamicFormIframe.contentDocument.document) ? dynamicFormIframe.contentDocument.document : dynamicFormIframe.contentDocument;
```

`contentDocument.document` is nonsense; that clause will never be taken. Chrome, not supporting the non-standard `contentWindow` property, will fall back to using `contentDocument`, which is a different object from `contentWindow`.

You only seem to want the document, not the window, so go for the standard `contentDocument` first, and only fall back to going via the window for IE where it's not supported:

```
var iframe= document.getElementById('dynamicFormIframe');
var idoc= 'contentDocument' in iframe? iframe.contentDocument : iframe.contentWindow.document;
idoc.open();
idoc.write(content);
idoc.close();
```

(Your example also has many apparent typos like mismatching tags, a JS string split over lines and a malformed doctype, is that a copy-and-paste error?)